# forcing a function to be pure

Tags: c++

In C++ it is possible to declare that a function is const, which means, as far as I understand, that the compiler ensures the function does not modify the object. Is there something analogous in C++ where I can require that a function is pure? If not in C++, is there a language where one can make this requirement?

If this is not possible, why is it possible to require functions to be const but not require them to be pure? What makes these requirements different?

For clarity, by pure I want there to be no side effects and no use of variables other than those passed into the function. As a result there should be no file reading or system calls etc.

Here is a clearer definition of side effects:

No modification to files on the computer that the program is run on and no modification to variables with scope outside the function. No information is used to compute the function other than variables passed into it. Running the function should return the same thing every time it is run.

NOTE: I did some more research and encountered [pure script](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PureScript)
(Thanks for jarod42's comment)

Based on a quick read of the wikipedia article I am under the impression you can require functions be pure in pure script, however I am not completely sure.

Comment: You can't force a function to be pure, you can only force yourself to write pure functions.

Comment: In Javascript, the const variable can be mutable, const just means can not reassignment.

Comment: Why do you want to flag a function as pure? How do you see this affecting how the function is used? (A `const` member function can be used when the caller has promised to not change the object via which the function is called. What analogous situation would be impacted by a "pure" flag?)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_programming_languages_by_type#Pure

Comment: @JaMiT, say you want to ensure there are no side effects to anything in the program. This would be similarly to how you might want to guarantee a function has no "side effects" to the object when using const.

Comment: @fred the only way to ensure no side effects is to be diligent about writing code that doesn't cause side effects. The compiler will not help you with that.

Comment: Define side effects. That affects the answer. I'm not aware of any keyword that does this, but again it depends on your definition of "side effects".

Comment: The language itself does not recognize the concept of pure functions but aparently some compilers do. At least GCC compiler has attributes that can be used to tell the compiler a function is pure: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Common-Function-Attributes.html#Common-Function-Attributes Not sure how well it works or if it fits your definition of pure.

Comment: _"Running the function should return the same thing every time it is run."_ -- isn't there supposed to be something like "with the same parameters" in this condition? Otherwise you've excluded some rather simple functions like `int add(int a, int b) { return a + b; }`.

Comment: Note that `const` only prevents the function from modifying the object directly. If it calls another function that modifies that object (for instance through a global), the object will still be modified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: No. There is no equivalent keyword called `pure` that constrains a function like `const` does.

However, if you have a specific global variable you'd like to remain untouched, you do have the option of `static type myVar`. This will require that only functions in that file will be able to use it, and nothing outside of that file. That means any function **outside** that file will be constrained to leave it alone.

As to "side effects", I will break each of them down so you know what options you have:

- No modification to files on the computer that the program is run on.

You can't constrain a function to do this that I'm aware. C++ just doesn't offer a way to constrain a function like this. You can, however, design a function to not modify any files, if you like.

- No modification to variables with scope outside the function.

Globals are the only variables you can modify outside a function's scope that I'm aware of, besides anything passed by pointer or reference as a parameter. Globals have the option of being constant or static, which will keep you from modifying them, but, beyond that, there's really nothing you can do that I'm aware.

- No information is used to compute the function other than variables passed into it.

Again, you can't constrain it to do so that I'm aware. However, you can design the function to work like this if you want.

- Running the function should return the same thing every time it is run.

I'm not sure I understand why you want to constrain a function like this, but no. Not that I'm aware. Again, you can design it like this if you like, though.

As to why C++ doesn't offer an option like this? I'm guessing reusability. It appears that you have a specific list of things you don't want your function to do. However, the likelihood that a lot of other C++ users as a whole will need this particular set of constraints often is very small. Maybe they need one or two at a time, but not all at once. It doesn't seem like it would be worth the trouble to add it.

The same, however, cannot be said about `const`. `const` is used all the time, especially in parameter lists. This is to keep data from getting modified if it's passed by reference, or something. Thus, the compiler needs to know what functions modify the object. It uses `const` in the function declaration to keep track of this. Otherwise, it would have no way of knowing. However, with using `const`, it's quite simple. It can just constrain the object to only use functions that guarantee that it remains constant, or uses the `const` keyword in the declaration if the function.

Thus, `const` get's a lot of reuse.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, C++ does not have a mechanism to ensure that a function has "no side effects and no use of variables other than those passed into the function." You can only force yourself to write pure functions, as mentioned by [Jack Bashford](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56301071/forcing-a-function-to-be-pure#comment99214046_56301071). The compiler can't check this for you.

There is a proposal ([N3744](https://wg21.link/n3744) Proposing `[[pure]]`). Here you can see that GCC and Clang already support `__attribute__((pure))`. Maybe it will be standardized in some form in the future revisions of C++.

Comment: could you elaborate as to why this is not possible while insuring that a function doesn't change its object, as with a const function, is possible?

Comment: @fred Well, C++ simply is not such a language. It doesn't check these things for you.

Comment: ok, sorry for the lack of clarity, but I am sort of asking two things here, first I want to know if C++ has this feature (which you have  answered, thank you for this) and second if this feature could exist and if not why.

Comment: @fred I have updated my answer. Not really much to say, genuinely ;-)

Comment: thanks for the update, I appreciate it. If possible do you know of other languages that may have this feature? If not do you think it would appropriate for me to ask a new question that directly asks for such a language, or would that be considered a duplicate of my question?

Comment: @fred Well ... That's really a hard question. I can't say for sure, but presumably there are. That's beyond my scope anyway ... You can probably ask such a question, but I can't say for sure it will get positive feedback.

Comment: In either case, thanks a lot for your time, I will accept your answer now

Comment: For the C++ standard to provide a way of enforcing function purity, it would first need to define what a pure function is. Does it?

Comment: @fred I was wrong. I have updated my answer to include more information.

Answer (score 0):

> In C++ it is possible to declare that a function is const, which means, as far as I understand, that the compiler ensures the function does not modify the object.

Not quite. The compiler will allow the object to be modified by (potentially ill-advised) use of [`const_cast`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/const_cast). So the compiler only ensures that the function does not *accidentally* modify the object.

> What makes these requirements [constant and pure] different?

They are different because one affects correct functionality while the other does not.

Suppose `C` is a container and you are iterating over its contents. At some point within the loop, perhaps you need to call a function that takes `C` as a parameter. If that function were to `clear()` the container, your loop will likely crash. Sure, you could build a loop that can handle that, but the point is that there are times when a caller needs assurance that the rug will not be pulled out from under it. Hence the ability to mark things `const`. If you pass `C` as a constant reference to a function, that function is promising to not modify `C`. This promise provides the needed assurance (even though, as I mentioned above, the promise can be broken).

I am not aware of a case where use of a non-pure function could similarly cause a program to crash. If there is no use for something, why complicate the language with it? If you can come up with a good use-case, maybe it is something to consider for a future revision of the language.

*(Knowing that a function is pure could help a compiler optimize code. As far as I know, it's been left up to each compiler to define how to flag that, as it does not affect functionality.)*